# Como agregar valores a un hashmap que tiene mas de 1 key

Tags: java

necesito por favor saber como puedo ingresar valores a un hashMap que tiene 2 key y un valor float-

Aqui está la declaración del hashMap

```html
HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, float[]>> notas = new HashMap<>();
```

aquí es como intentó agregar datos a ese hashmap

```html
notas.put(1,"MAT001",[6.0]);
```

pero me dice que está mal la sintaxis

me podrian ayudar por favor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intento poder agregar valores al hashmap y espero aprender a utilizar este tipo de colecciones.

Comment: Por favor su ayuda con este tema.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo tenes estructurado de la siguiente manera

```
HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, float[]>> notas = new HashMap<>();
```

debes primero llenar el el valor v=float[] y la llave k=String

```
HashMap<String, float[]>

HashMap<String,float[]>sub_notas=new HashMap<>();
float[]array= {1.3f,2.4f,0.4f};
sub_notas.put("MAT001",array);
```

ahora pasas a llenar el `HashMap` notas valor v=hashMap<String,float[]> y llave k=Integer

```
notas.put(1,sub_notas);
```

para ver los datos seria lo mismo primero iterar el HashMap principal y luego acceder al interno que es ta como valor

```
 for(Integer k:notas.keySet()){
         System.out.println(k+" "); 
      for (String j:notas.get(k).keySet()) {
          System.out.println(j+" "+Arrays.toString(notas.get(k).get(j))); 
        
      }
    }
```